# How to prove the monotonicity of the following function? $f(x) = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^K\ln(1+a_ix)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^K\ln(1+\frac{1}{2}a_ix)}$

Tags: logarithmic-energy

How to prove the monotonicity of the following function?

$f(x) = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^K\ln(1+a_ix)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^K\ln(1+\frac{1}{2}a_ix)}$.
where $a_i>0$, $\forall i$, $x>0$.

I have proved that $\frac{h_i(x)}{g_i(x)}=\frac{\ln(1+a_ix)}{\ln(1+\frac{1}{2}a_ix)}$ is a monotonically decreasing function with $x$. Actually, $f(x)$ is also monotonically decreasing with $x$, which can be proved by simple simulation. But I can't give the rigorous proof.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know if OPs are pinged when comments are added to solutions, so I'm adding this to alert mingzhanzhang.

Comment: There is no way. The statement is false in general (which makes me extremely curious about what you mean by the "proof by simple simulation": I hope you haven't just considered a finite number of random sets of parameters)

Comment: @fedja: When $x$ is very large so that $a_ix \gg 2$, then the ``1'' in the logarithm can be ignored and the statement can be proved. Besides, the simulation Matlab codes are below, I have tried many times and still cann't find the counterexample, Could you present some examples? K = 10;
m = 0;
n = 100;
a = m + (n-m) .* rand(K,1);
x = [0.001:0.01:10];
f1 = sum( log(1 + a*x  ), 1 );
f2 = sum( log(1 + a*x/2), 1 );
f = f1./f2;
figure
plot(x, f, '-r')

Answer (score 2):

OK, I put the remark yesterday at night just to prevent people from wasting time on attempts to prove the statement. Now it is time to post the explanation. Note that if $\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$ is non-increasing and $F,G>0$, then $\frac{F'(x)}{F(x)}\le \frac{G'(x)}{G(x)}$ and, in particular, if $G'(x)-cG(x)\le 0$ for some positive $c$ and $x$, then $F'(x)-cF(x)\le 0$.

Now let us look at what functions we have. Repeating the summands, if necessary, and approximating reals by rationals, we can put $F(x)=\int\log (1+2ax)\,d\mu(a)$ and $G(x)=\int\log(1+ax)\,d\mu(a)$ where $\mu$ is any finite sum of Dirac point masses with positive coefficients. So, if our inequality holds, we must have that $\int \left[\frac{a}{1+ax}-c\log(1+ax)\right]\,d\mu(a)\le 0$ implies that $\int \left[\frac{2a}{1+2ax}-c\log(1+2ax)\right]\,d\mu(a)\le 0$ for every fixed $x,c>0$ and every $\mu$ of the above kind. We'll take $x=1$, $c\in(0,1)$.
Then, by the general abstract duality nonsense, for any finite set $A$ of points $a>0$, we must be able to produce a non-negative $\lambda$ such that
$$
\frac{2a}{1+2a}-c\log(1+2a)\le\lambda\left[\frac{a}{1+a}-c\log(1+a)\right]
$$
for all $a\in A$. Now just take $A$ consisting of $2$ points: $a_1\approx 0$ and $a_2\approx+\infty$.
Looking at $a_1$, we get essentially $2a_1(1-c)\le \lambda a_1(1-c)$, so $\lambda$ cannot be noticeably less than $2$. Looking at $a_2$, we get essentially $-c\log a_2\le \lambda(-c\log a_2)$, so $\lambda$ cannot be noticeably greater, than $1$. But this leaves us no room!